# AWS Redshift Terraform module: final_snapshot_identifier

Tags: terraform, amazon-redshift, terraform-provider-aws

I use the AWS Redshift Terraform module, https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-redshift to provision redshift. Per document, final_snapshot_identifier is not required. But, I got the error,
Error: only alphanumeric characters and hyphens allowed in "final_snapshot_identifier".
The document says, "final_snapshot_identifier: (Optional) The identifier of the final snapshot that is to be created immediately before deleting the cluster. If this parameter is provided, 'skip_final_snapshot' must be false", I can solve this problem by adding the code,

```
final_snapshot_identifier  = var.final_snapshot_identifier
skip_final_snapshot        = true
```

But, why?

```
module "redshift" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/redshift/aws"
  version = "2.7.0"

  #redshift_subnet_group_name = var.redshift_subnet_group_name
  subnets                    = data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.redshift_subnets
  #parameter_group_name       = var.parameter_group_name
  cluster_identifier         = var.cluster_identifier
  cluster_database_name      = var.cluster_database_name
  encrypted                  = false
  cluster_master_password    = var.cluster_master_password
  cluster_master_username    = var.cluster_master_username
  cluster_node_type          = var.cluster_node_type
  cluster_number_of_nodes    = var.cluster_number_of_nodes
  enhanced_vpc_routing       = false
  publicly_accessible        = true
  vpc_security_group_ids     = [module.sg.this_security_group_id]
  final_snapshot_identifier  = var.final_snapshot_identifier
  skip_final_snapshot        = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are providing value for final snapshot idenitifier,skip_final_snapshot should be false. But you have given as true

final_snapshot_identifier  = var.final_snapshot_identifier
skip_final_snapshot        = true